# Heroku logs not working

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I deployed my simple RoR app to heroku but i seem to be unable to see its logs.
I am doing `heroku logs` but this is producing no result at all.

Am i missing something here?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku had some issues about logging this weekend. Fortunately, now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

What are saying 'heroku addons' command? There should be 'logging:basic' or 'logging:expanded' response. Did you prepare 'heroku addons:add logging:basic'?

Comment: Yes. I added the logging:basic addon.

Comment: In such case maybe you write in log only DEBUG messages? By default, logging on the Heroku platform is set to INFO.  You have to manually correct this if you want to see DEBUG messages in log.

Comment: That came up in one of my searches and i also did that with no luck though.